# .Net 6 Docker Container Error "System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'ole32.dll' or one of its dependencies"

Tags: docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I opened a Web Core Api with .NET 6 via Visual Code 2022. I added following lines, it is working correctly on my local but when I tried to run it on my docker-desktop it craches. The code using this package: "TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Core.Design"

```
            TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();

            Uri url = UrlBuilder.Build("Graybox.Simulator.1");

            using (var server = new OpcDaServer(url))
            {                
                server.Connect();

                OpcDaGroup group = server.AddGroup("MyGroup");
                group.IsActive = true;

                var definition1 = new OpcDaItemDefinition
                {
                    ItemId = "numeric.random.int64",
                    IsActive = true
                };
                var definition2 = new OpcDaItemDefinition
                {
                    ItemId = "numeric.random.int32",
                    IsActive = true
                };

                OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = { definition1, definition2 };
                OpcDaItemResult[] results = group.AddItems(definitions);

                foreach (OpcDaItemResult result in results)
                {
                    if (result.Error.Failed)
                        Console.WriteLine("Error adding items: {0}", result.Error);
                }

                while (true)
                {
                    OpcDaItemValue[] values = group.Read(group.Items, OpcDaDataSource.Device);
                    Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}", Convert.ToString(values[0].Value));


                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5045

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5045

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["OPC-DA.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "OPC-DA.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "OPC-DA.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "OPC-DA.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "OPC-DA.dll"]
```

I also switched my docker-desktop target as Windows. When the lines is runned it crashes on because of the first line.

Error :

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
Connection id "0HMN2H4AOJ5LQ", Request id "0HMN2H4AOJ5LQ:00000002": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'ole32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libole32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is the NuGet package you're referencing in your project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TitaniumAS.Opc.Client. That package is built for .NET Framework, not .NET Core. Your build output is likely showing warnings about that fact. Something like:

```
Package 'TitaniumAS.Opc.Client 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net6.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project
```

Calling .NET Framework assemblies from .NET Core *can* work but it's not guaranteed to work. So that's the first issue.

The next issue is related to the target platform. Since the Titanium assembly is for .NET Framework, it'll only run on Windows. Based on the error message you provided, it looks like you're targeting Linux containers. So that's not going to work because of this Titanium dependency. It's trying to find a Windows DLL that obviously doesn't exist on Linux. Instead you'll want to target Windows containers instead. So you'd first need to update Docker Desktop to target Windows containers instead.

You shouldn't need to change your Dockerfile. The tag you're using, `6.0` is dynamic and will work for both Linux and Windows, giving you the appropriate image based on the container platform type you're targeting.